# Window tabs at the bottom disappeared

Tags: pharo

At some moment for unknown reason window tabs that are always housed at the bottom of [pharo](/questions/tagged/pharo) window disappeared. Is there any way to bring them back except for opening a new image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Pharo versions < 2:

```
Project showWorldTaskbar: true.
```

In Pharo versions >= 2 there is a 'Taskbar' preference which you can toggle or you can evaluate:

```
World showWorldTaskbar: true.
```

Answer (score 3):

actually, is:

```
World showWorldTaskbar: true.
```